How do I prevent VS Code CLI from opening a new window?
code --help should show the command line options, see VS Code docs.
In my case this command opens a new code window.
I'm using Windows cmd.exe; the PATH variable is set correctly, verified by where code.
It's the same with other command like code --version.
How can I use the CLI?
Is my installation corrupt?
My setup:
Version: 1.92.2 (user setup)
Commit: fee1edb8d6d72a0ddff41e5f71a671c23ed924b9
Date: 2024-08-14T17:29:30.058Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

